# Can't Embedded Image Picked By 'expo-mage-picker' Into Rich Text in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to customize the react-native-pell-rich-editor rich text editor to insert the insert base64 image into the rich text content. I am using expo-image-picker to select the image and after selecting I am trying to called the insertImage function to attach the image in to the current text content. But this function doesn't getting called and image uri is a null value whole the time. Really appreciate any help to fixed this issue. If there's any other ways I could try to attach images in to the rich text editor content in base64 I liked to hear.

```
    import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { actions, RichEditor, RichToolbar } from 'react-native-pell-rich-editor';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'; // Import FileSystem


const handleHead = ({ tintColor }) => <Text style={{ color: tintColor }}>H1</Text>;

const Create = () => {
  const richText = useRef();
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState('');

  console.log("image uri", imageUri)

  const openGalleryClickProfile = async () => {
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.status !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: false,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled && result.uri) { 
      let base64Img = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
      let imgUri = `data:image/jpg;base64,${base64Img}`;
      setImageUri(imgUri);
      insertImage()
    }
  };

  const insertImage = () => {
    if (imageUri) {
      console.log(insertImage)
      richText.current?.insertImage(imageUri);
      console.log("image uri after insertion", imageUri); 
      setImageUri(''); 
    }
  };



  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Description:</Text>
          <RichEditor
            ref={richText}
            onChange={(descriptionText) => {
              console.log('descriptionText:', descriptionText);
            }}
          />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>

      <RichToolbar
        editor={richText}
        actions={[
          actions.setBold,
          actions.setItalic,
          actions.setUnderline,
          actions.heading1,
          actions.insertImage,
        ]}
        iconMap={{
          [actions.heading1]: handleHead,
        }}
        onPressAddImage={openGalleryClickProfile}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Create;
```